# How to create symbolic link to a path that contains unicode characters?

Tags: c, unix, unicode, symlink, fcntl

I am using UNIX function [`symlink()`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSLTBW_2.3.0/com.ibm.zos.v2r3.bpxbd00/rtsym.htm) to link a path that contains Unicode characters. However, when I read the link, it is returning `?` instead of Unicode characters.

This is what my method looks like :

```
if (symlink("symlink.jpg", "/real/path/光芒.jpg") != 0)
    warn("symlink() error\n");
else //symlink creation successful
```

The symlink is created successfully at this point, however the link looks something like this:

```
 symlink.jpg -> /real/path/??.jpg
```

I was expecting the link to look like this:

```
 symlink.jpg -> /real/path/光芒.jpg
```

Can anyone tell me why this is happening? 
Any fix or alternative library/function recommendation would be appreciated.

Additional information:

1. I am suspecting that library [`unistd.h`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/unistd.h.html) or [`fcntl.h`](http://unix.superglobalmegacorp.com/Net2/newsrc/sys/fcntl.h.html) might not have unicode support. Because when I use `creat()` or `open()` to create a new file called `光芒.jpg`, it actually creates a file called `??.jpg`.
2. My development environment and compiler has unicode support. For example, `fprint()` can use unicode characters.

Comment: As far as I know, it should just work.  As far as the `symlink` function call is concerned, those filenames are just sequences of bytes.  I suspect the `?`'s you're seeing are coming from the `ls` command, not because those are the actual characters in the link name.  So you might try changing your locale settings when you run `ls`.

Comment: Does the symlink actually work (i.e. can you open symlink.jpg in an image editor or web browser?) If not, you might have an encoding-related error. `ls -l symlink.jpg | od -tx1 -Ax` would get you a hex dump (you can alternatively pipe to `xxd` or `hexdump -C` in place of `od -tx1 -Ax` if they're installed on your system). The required byte sequences depend on your locale, but encoding info for the characters can be found [here for 光](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/5149/charset_support.htm) and [here for 芒](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/8292/charset_support.htm).

Comment: Minor correction to my previous comment: you'd want to open `/real/path/光芒.jpg` since that's the new symlink to the file `symlink.jpg`, though I just realized this wouldn't necessarily validate the proper encoding of the symlink name. I also believed `symlink()` used `path_to_symlink, path_to_link_target` argument order (i.e. `dest, src` like `strcpy`, `strcat`, and many other C functions), but it's the other way around. Either way, my point remains: try to determine the bytes used for those characters.